# AngularJS Backendless Development 'Unexpected request' of templates issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working on a project that needs the backend to be mocked while the frontend implementation is being made.

I have a gulp structure that loads `/**/*.mock.js` files only for tests and while serving the source for development. I use this `.mock.js` files to mock test data and services and to intercept http calls for backendless development. The file looks like this:

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';

  var mockResponseData = {
    'mock': 'data'
  };

  angular
    .module('module.name')
    .value('mockResponseData', mockResponseData)
    .config(config)
    .run(run);

  /** @ngInject */
  function config($provide) {
    $provide.decorator('$httpBackend', angular.mock.e2e.$httpBackendDecorator);
  }

  /** @ngInject */
  function run($httpBackend) {

    $httpBackend.whenPOST(/\/api\/path\/$/)
      .respond(function() {
        return [200, mockResponseData];
      });

    $httpBackend.whenGET(/^\w+.*/).passThrough();
    $httpBackend.whenPOST(/^\w+.*/).passThrough();
    $httpBackend.whenPUT(/^\w+.*/).passThrough();
    $httpBackend.whenDELETE(/^\w+.*/).passThrough();
  }

})();
```

As you can see, I already have the `.passThrough()` applied (which is the common solution for the `Unexpected request` issue) and it works just fine when just one `.mock.js` file like this exists. After creating the second file, the `Unexpected request` errors start to appear:

```
Error: Unexpected request: GET 'path/to/template.html'
```

After trying some things, I realized that the problem could be with the way I'm injecting `$httpBackend`. To avoid it from being injected in the `dist` files and to keep the project structure modular, I have to inject it via `$provide` instead of directly in the module's definition, in each module that needs it. Which is done in the `config` block of the code above.

If the `$provide.decorator(...)` line is removed from all but one `.mock.js` files, everything works fine again (except that the run block from the files with the line removed would start to complain about the non-existent `$httpBackend`, but this is not the issue here).

So, any idea of what this could be?

Thanks in advance!

P.S.: I can't miss the modularity structure and the `.mock.js` files cannot be included in the `dist` build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I've solved this a while ago and now I'm answering here for future reference.

The basic problem is that I was injecting the `$httpBackend` service using the `$provide.decorator()` method, which according to the documentation, works like this:

> Register a **service decorator** with the [$injector](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector). A service decorator intercepts the creation of a service, allowing it to override or modify the behavior of the service. The object returned by the decorator may be the original service, or a new service object which replaces or wraps and delegates to the original service.

Injecting the service like this was necessary to avoid injecting it when it wouldn't be used, but somehow, if you decorate this same service twice, AngularJS get confused and starts to throw the errors described in the question.

So, the solution is to create a `.mock.js` file for the main module. This way it will inject the service only once and avoid the problem:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('mainModuleName')
    .config(config);

  /** @ngInject */
  function config($provide) {
    $provide.decorator('$httpBackend', angular.mock.e2e.$httpBackendDecorator);
  }

})();
```

Please note that you can still add more decorators to the service as follows:

```
$provide.decorator('$httpBackend', function($delegate, $injector) {
  // Your decorator...
});
```

As long as you don't inject `angular.mock.e2e.$httpBackendDecorator` more than once.